# Docker – exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker

I have used this

> docker exec -it 027285d69613 bash

And got this error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The truth is, not every image is using the bash shell; try sh shell.

> docker exec -it 027285d69613 sh

Refer to this blog for more details.
https://mkyong.com/docker/docker-exec-bash-executable-file-not-found-in-path/